# How to summarize the excel files with password in a folder

Tags: excel

i am quite new to coding and would like to perform below actions.

Assume we have several excel files name

```
excel_A.xlsx
excel_B.xlsx
excel_C.xlsx
```

and they are all protected by same password "hello" and stored under folder path `"\\U\desktop\sample\202001"`

```
And there are 12 folders named 202001 - 202012 under folder "sample" with same format excels in each folder but may have different number of excels.
so the full picture looks sth similar to below

>Desktop
>> sample
>>>202001
>>>>excel_A,
excel_B,
excel_C
>>>202002
>>>>excel_A,
excel_B,
excel_C,
excel_D
>>>202003
>>>>excel_A,
excel_B,
excel_C
>>>202004
>>>>excel_A,
excel_B,
excel_C,
excel_D,
excel_E

so on until 202012

So basically what i want to do is to count the number of rows of data in each excels and provide a new excel file with a table like below format
    
| root folder   | Sample | Sample| Sample| Sample| Sample|
| ------------- | ------ |------ |------ |------ |------ |
| name of excel | 202001 |202002 |202003 |...    |202012 |
| Excel_A       | 23     |33     |2      |...    |19     |
| Excel_B       | 35     |61     |83     |...    |90     |
| Excel_C       | 108    |96     |81     |...    |14     |
| Excel_D       | -      |32     |-      |...    |7      |
| Excel_E       | -      |-      |-      |...    |3      |
| Excel_F       | -      |-      |-      |...    |-      |
```

Comment: To qualify for help on this forum you need to show your own effort.

Comment: question :  how did you access the content of the ".. excel files with password.." ? (need to know the method to assist on summarizing..)